# Working with local filesystem and MySQL database in Docker, tensorflow, Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-machine

I recently switched to a new (Windows 10) computer and need to pick up some development that I was doing in tensorflow. [The only way that I can find to run tensorflow is through Docker](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/), which I have working just fine (a bit different than the linked article) with `docker run -d -P engineero/tensorflow:df_build` (my image made by modifying the main repo's Dockerfile to pull in some extra dependencies). I have two remaining problems, however:

1. I cannot figure out how to use and modify my existing jupyter notebooks in the Docker container that I run.
2. I have no idea how to connect to the MySQL database that I have running on my machine.

For **1** I have tried adding `-v /c/Users/path/to/my/files:/tensorflow/my_files` to the `docker run` command, as well as `/c/Users/path/to/my/files/*:/tensorflow/my_files`. For both of these, I get a `/tensorflow/my_files` directory in my VM, but it is empty. I need to be able to use the existing notebooks (and some other files) from my file system and have changes that I make to these files persist on my file system.

For **2**, I really have no idea. The MySQL database is currently running on Windows `localhost`, but if I reference `localhost` in my scripts to connect to the database, that will try to connect to the daemon (I think), which is not the same: `docker-machine ip` does not give me 127.0.0.1 (`localhost` from the perspective of Windows), and the IP/port that I have to connect to for jupyter notebook is some other address that I get from `docker-machine ip` and `docker ps -l`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I am totally on the wrong page, I would welcome some discussion of the right way to go about this. I am working through the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/) now, but so far I have not found a solution.

**Edit:** Number **2** has been answered, but number **1** is still at large.

Comment: For1: try the following, hour it will be helpful. //docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Docker on Windows, So I cannot answer your first question. However, I could answer your second question. When you run Docker on Windows/ Mac, it runs inside a VM as you probable know already. When you call `docker run`, it creates a container which can be considered as another VM (Not actually a VM, but for some purposes only). So, when you refer to `localhost` from inside the container, it will try to connect to the `localhost` inside that container. To overcome this situation, you should use the IP address of the VM (192.168.99.100 for Mac, I guess it's the same for Windows as well), whatever the IP address you got from `docker-machine ip`. If you happen to use the Linux, you should use the actual IP address of the host.

I edited the following based on your comment. The above is true only if you are running MySQL in Docker. If you are trying to connect to MySQL running natively, you should use the actual IP address of the PC (which you can find by using `ipconfig` on command prompt on Windows) irrespective of the OS.

I am not sure how familiar you are with the concept of VMs. VMs are like separate PCs, but the difference is that they running inside your PC. If you want to talk to another PC from your PC, easiest way is using the external IP address. 
p.s. You also should allow your MySQL to accept remote connection. [This link](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/09/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows/) explains how you do it.

Comment: So you're saying I should tell my script to connect to the docker IP (it actually is 192.168.99.100) even though my database is running on Windows localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your question. Missing the point that you are running MySQL natively (I was rushing out when I was trying to answer this question). I have corrected my answer above.

Comment: Oh great, thanks! That makes sense, I just hadn't thought of it because I'm used to not needing to run this stuff in a VM. I will give that a shot.

Comment: I ended up giving up on Docker for now. I found installing Ubuntu in a partition easier than getting the VM and Windows file systems to play nice. I think this would work for the MySQL server, but I'm not really running it now to check. Thanks though!